# Ambient Sounds (not music!)

Tags: tools, sound-effects

I'm currently running a campaign with highly interactive players who do a lot of exploring, debating, politicizing, weaving intrigues, etc., etc. (We rarely have real fights, maybe once every 5-10 hours played) Music is TSFH, Zack Hemsey, Audiomachine, etc (I can *really* recommend this for your action / climax playlist!), but this is mostly epic-trailer-music, not fitting "common actions".

Especially for exploring and "everyday conversations" (in a pub or a tavern for example), I need ambient **sounds**. (In a murky cave: The sound of little creatures running around, water dropping from the ceiling or in a pub indifferent conversation, laughter, I think you catch the drift.)

Are there any smaller or larger sound file archives for that?

To clarify: I'm thankful for app suggestions and will definitely look into them, but a straight-up collection of sounds would be enough.

Comment: Megge, I removed the unrelated details from your question, as it is an unwelcome distraction in the rpg.se format. But if you think that information would be nice to have, you can very well ask another question related to music, and answer it yourself (perfectly legit here). That would be much more appreciated. You can just copy the details from [your previous revision here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/19279/5)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Ambiance](http://ambianceapp.com/) - sound effect mixer, allows you to make a playlist.  They have a huge list of sounds you can download and mix as you like.  I think you can also upload sounds as well.

The app has versions for IOS, Android, and desktops.  My wife uses the IOS app daily so that's the only one I've see work.  It seems simple and clear to me.

Here are some other sources of sounds, no app required.

- [Sound Jay - Ambient Sound Effects](http://www.soundjay.com/ambient-sounds.html)
- [Ambience | public domain sounds](http://www.pdsounds.org/tag/ambience)
- [Free Sound Effects, Royalty Free Sound Effects, Nature Sounds](http://www.partnersinrhyme.com/pir/PIRsfx.shtml)
- [Freesound.org - pack: horror ambience by klankbeeld](http://www.freesound.org/people/klankbeeld/packs/9250/)

Comment: There's a Lite version as well, if you want to try it out first.

Comment: Wow, this list is neat! I think this - combined with Ambiance, which I pretty surely will buy after testing it in one session - solves my question!

Answer (score 5):

If you have an iOS device, **[DMDJ](http://www.bluefacegames.com/applications/dmdj/)** might be what you are looking for.

It is a tool for selecting and playing ambient sounds as well as music during a RPG session, and has an extensive library covering much of the soundscape of a fantasy game and some modern+sci-fi as well.

The sound mixing engine allows you to select the *intensity* of an ambient sound, and that's not just volume, so a low intensity crowd is few people on the street that seamlessly turns into a bustling avenue at high intensity.

Comment: DMDJ has an excellent ambient-track engine that generates the mix of effects dynamically, not by looping a pre-recorded track, so there isn't ever that moment where you realise you've heard this same set of sounds in a previous loop. Its greatest drawback is that its sounds are fixed and since it tries to be multi-genre it has a limited selection that I found useful for my game: mostly Town: Hall with People, Town: City, Dungeon: Haunted, Dungeon: Sewer, and Nature: Cave. A lack of Dungeon variety is especially notable. However, those I could use were *very* effective and I used them often.

Answer (score 3):

For ambiant sounds I can recomend [gomix.it](http://gomix.it). It is a collection of sounds that you can play straight or mix and there are plenty of sounds to choose from. You can download and also share.

Here is an example I made of an [autumnal camp fire](http://gomix.it/autumn-camp).

Comment: Another sound scape (this time Star Wars) for the fashionable [Cato Neimoidia Hilton](http://gomix.it/catoniemoidia-hilton).

Comment: Len, I can't comment on your question over at Parenting so I'll try to slip a comment in here.  Let me know when you've read it so I can delete it as it's irrelevant to Games.  If the current approach is not sufficient, I will share a medical approach that child psychiatrists sometimes use for pediatric anxiety: tiny dose of something in the Valium family, e.g. Xanax or Ativan, around the clock.  For a small child you'd need a liquid formulation.  I'm not recommending this, just sharing info so you can ask questions when you talk with the doctor.

Comment: @aparente001 thanks for the suggestion, thankfully I don't think we are anywhere near that level.

Comment: Well, in that case, the following might be enough.  In a Longest Shortest Time (parenting podcast) episode, a professional clown who is also a dad shared a trick he used during potty training.  Knowing that his son favors blue and dislikes green, he put a blue potty and a green potty in the play room.  When he knows it's about time to pee, he pushes the green potty, and his son indignantly chooses the blue potty.

Answer (score -1):

There were a couple of Kickstarer campaigns featuring ambience sound - [there have been two](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1281758745/professional-mp3-background-loops-for-role-playing) [by Plate Mail games](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1281758745/pro-tabletop-gaming-audio-collection) including background loops, monsters, traps, spells, etc. It is possible that past Kickstarter campaigns are offering their product for sale through online channels; Plate Mail Games is selling theirs on their [online store](http://platemailgames.com/).

An on-going Kickstarter for you to consider would be [Realmsound.](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/105982873/realmsound-project-20?ref=category)